# Switching network from netmask 24 to 22

Tags: windows-server-2008, subnet, ip-address

I currently have a firewall set up as x.x.1.1 and a secondary of x.x.2.1 on the firewall. On the DHCP server I have a superscope with 2 scopes handing out DHCP addresses. I was told it would be best practices to re-configure the network to use x.x.1.1 mask of 255.255.252.0 /22 so that all of our addresses are on the same subnet.

I am really considering this because any device on x.x.2.1 as of right now cannot be seen by stations with x.x.1.x unless i configure a network path of \\x.x.1.x\share instead of the server name. It is a little irritating but its not worth changing the whole network and all static devices. Is there any other reasons to change this?

Comment: That sounds like a DNS problem, not an ip addressing problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no compelling reason to use two subnets (segregating broadcast traffic is the most common, and also the reason that name resolution is broken), joining the subnets is the simplest solution.

The name resolution issue can also be resolved by [installing a WINS server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710463(v=ws.10).aspx) on the network. WINS will enable NetBIOS name resolution across subnets by serving as a central repository for hostnames in the broadcast-based protocol.

Note: the link is part of a tutorial and mentions irrelevant details but the article is explicit and succinct in its explanation of WINS.